# angular detecting input file information

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im currently trying to get to grips with angular and need to upload a file to a server, but I think Im running into problems even before getting to that stage.

My problem here is that my `ng-model` is showing an empty object as a result. It was my understanding that it would alert the file information in the controller...

From reading other questions and answers on SO I figured the directive would return the file information.

HTML:

```
  <form name="addNewEvent" >
        Image:<br /><input data-file id="id_image" name="image" ng-model="eventFormData.eventImage" type="file"><br />
        First name:    <br/><input type="text" ng-model="eventFormData.eventName"> <br />
        // More inputs 
  </form>
```

JS:

```
var eventApp = angular.module('eventApp', ['ngRoute']);

eventApp.directive('file', function() {
    return {
        require:"ngModel",
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, el, attrs, ngModel){
            el.bind('change', function(event){
                var files = event.target.files;
                window.alert(files[0]);
                var file = files[0];

                ngModel.$setViewValue(file);
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And in my controller...

```
$scope.submitForm = function(eventFormData) {

    window.alert($scope.eventFormData.eventImage.toSource());


};
```

Comment: can you please paste your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I had done one out but was running into issues and was going off the original code trying to get it going in jsfiddle, but I think I may have found the solution, I wasnt using `readAsDataURL`